# Angular9 debugElement.classes['my-class'] now returns undefined

Tags: angular, angular9, testbed

I'm updating a repo that used to use Angular 8.
In a test, using TestBed, I'm checking if a class exists using: 
`fixture.debugElement.classes['my-class'].toBe(false)`

After updating to Angular 9, this test no longer works, as the expression no longer returns false when the class doesn't exist, it returns undefined.
I've fixed the test using:
`fixture.debugElement.classes['my-class'].toBeFalsy()`
by i'm afraid something else is failing silenty.

Checking Angular documentation, classes should only return a boolean:
`classes: {
    [key: string]: boolean;
}`

Is there any situation where `classes` will return undefined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Ivy documentation says:

> DebugElement.classes returns undefined for classes that were added and then subsequently removed (previously, classes added and later removed would have a value of false).

https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility

(I was having exatcly the same issue, and it broke a dozen of my unit tests as well)